# Is my pegboard stand design reasonable?

Tags: woodworking, joints, frame

I have an idea of building a pegboard stand, for the purpose of holding kids art supplies.  For example, buckets with pencils, markers, pens, paintbrushes.  Possibly also some trays for papers.

Below is a picture of the idea i have.  In red, I thought maybe there could be additional supports for stability.  I want it to be movable, instead of mounting to a wall.  I want to be able to slide a desk under the board as well.

I have ZERO experience with woodworking, or building anything really.  Looking for pointers on how to get started and/or any reliable Internet resources for beginners I can research from.  I thought building a wood frame would be most economical and practical in getting materials.

The pegboard I have in mind is 48" x 24", and probably 36" inch from floor.

[image: pegboard stand]

Comment: looks like a good start to me! get some 1x4s and build it like you've pictured. Sandwich the pegboard between two of them and  use screws for fasteners.

Comment: That looks like the chalkboards we had in school, though they had casters on the bottom to make them movable. It's a proven design for sure!

Comment: First hint - draw to scale. If it's 4 feet wide by 2 feet high and raised 3 feet off the floor, draw it that way, and then other things drawn on it will be able to be measured to see what size they are...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a good rigid frame. I don't think 1x4 will do it, pegboard is very floppy.  I'd probably suggest 2x4, and use two sheets of pegboard to conceal them some, sandwiching the 2x4s between two sheets.  The other advantage is that you won't see the hooks from the opposing side.  One complication is that it's likely to be top heavy so you need to make the base "outriggers" quite long so it doesn't fall over.

It will be pretty simple other than the angled cuts, which you can figure out empirically by laying out the inverted T portion of the base, and then cutting the braces to fit.  There are many good introductory books and websites, take a look at Taunton Press, I'm sure they have plenty. When you buy your lumber get "KD" 2x4s rather than run of the mill stuff which will have high water content and tend to warp as it dries. The stuff you want will feel relatively light for it's size.  Sight down each edge and look for twists or warps.

OK, that get you off to a good start?

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good. Just remember that kids are *incredibly inventive*, off the charts, so be prepared for them to try things you don't expect. Like: using the pegs and board like a climbing wall. So make so you can "fail safe", eg have long feet painted a bright color so that it doesn't tip over on them and you don't trip over the feet when heading to your desk.

Kids. Gotta love the little monkeys.